# Distinct Results in Hibernate Criteria API Inner Join

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a `Request` object which can have multiple `Authors`. The mapping is defined correctly.

In the Criteria API I define a restriction that does a Join on AUTHORS_T.

```
Criteria criteriaQuery = session.createCriteria(Request.class);

// Create alias for Authors table
criteriaQuery.createAlias("Authors", "auth", JoinType.INNER_JOIN);

// Define restriction: LIKE on auth.firstName / auth.LastName
String authorNameForQuery = "%" + searchCriteria.getAuthorName().trim() + "%";
Disjunction firstOrLast = Restrictions.disjunction();
firstOrLast.add(Restrictions.ilike("auth.lastname", authorNameForQuery) )
           .add(Restrictions.ilike("auth.firstname", authorNameForQuery) )
criteriaQuery.add(firstOrLast);
```

Resulting SQL:

```
select ... // one-by-one
   from requests_t _this 
   inner join authors_t auth_ on this_.ID = auth_.REQUEST_ID
   where ...
```

Everything works but I get multiple identical Requests back for each Author.

E.g. if `RequestID=111` has 4 `author`s, I get 4 results back, but I should only get 1. This is the result of the INNER JOIN.

Is there a way in the Criteria API for me to avoid this and get the Distinct Request objects?

Comment: maybe .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY) on your criteria would help?